# Rails App: pipeline asset not working as expected

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm a ruby and rails novice so please have patience with me.

I have a SASS file (stats.css.scss) in rails that is loaded correctly in my development enviroment, but doesn't get loaded in my production enviroment. I know is the asset pipeline that is causing this, but have made several attempts and couldn't figure out what is wrong. Here's what I got:

In my site/app/assets/stylesheet folder I have the stats.css.scss file

The index.html.erb file is loading the SASS file like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stats", media: "all" %>
```

When I check the source code for the page loaded (Ctrl+U in google chrome) in **development enviroment**, I see this

```
<link href="/assets/stats.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

which is what I expected, as it does look like the JS included in the asset pipeline. But in **production enviroment** the source code shows this

```
<link href="/stylesheets/stats.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Anybody can help me figure out what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile` to precompile assets for production deploy?  Also, it is generally better if you can use the manifest files to require assets than doing them one by one.  You might want to take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.

Comment: I did on my local machine, but our deploy is a bit more complex: we push the code to github and automated servers take care of the rest. Should I do that before pushing? Any other advice?

Comment: Are the asset files getting into github?

Comment: Yeah. I pushed my site/app/assets/stylesheet/stats.css.scss file to github.

Comment: Do you see minified asset files in /public/assets on your local m/c and in github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advice:** don't compile assets in production. It's not necessary and prone to problems.

---

Since you haven't mentioned it, I'm going to guess you don't have `stats.css` added to the precompile config. Add the following to `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( stats.css )
```

The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) now suggests doing it like this in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( stats.css )
```

Why is this necessary? From the guide:

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (this will include all image assets automatically) from app/assets folders including your gems:
>
> ```
> [ Proc.new { |filename, path| path =~ /app\/assets/ && !%w(.js .css).include?(File.extname(filename)) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
> ```

In other words, if you want `stats.css.scss` to be precompiled at any point, you need to explicitly tell Sprockets to do so.

Comment: I thought the point was to precompile assets so that they can be served faster.  This sounds like a possible fix for the problem but IMO better would be to follow the asset pipeline guide and use manifest files etc.  If you do that properly, you don't need to worry about `config.assets.precompile` or doing anything for any individual file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with precompiling css and js files in addition to `application.js` and `application.css`. This is good practice in larger applications. I'm not suggesting against precompiling assets; I'm suggesting he not do it **on the production server**. Precompile as part of deployment and `rsync` the assets. You don't need things like ruby, node.js, etc. on the production server for the purpose of asset compilation, you don't need to commit compiled assets to a VCS, and you guarantee a build won't include newer versions of assets than intended from non-strict dependency specs.

Comment: That solved! Except it was located in a different file: in my case it was on site/config/enviroments/production.rb There I found a list with several other .css files that are pre-compiled. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As long as they're all appending to the `precompile` config option, placing it in `config/application.rb` is just fine. If, for example, you have a `staging` environment too, putting this sort of thing in `config/application.rb` is arguably better because it avoids duplication between `production.rb` and `staging.rb` in `config/environment`.